# Progress bar with multiple Ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

In short, I have a javascript array with some csv files to load into a mysql database, and created a script that makes ajax () calls to a php page that handles uploading the file into the database. On the client side there is a progressbar that moves with each file loaded into the database. If I use 'async: false', everything goes ok but browser is blocked and I do not want this thing, but if I use 'async: true', everything happens very quickly and progressbar does not keep pace with each file loaded synchronously. Can anyone structure the code so that ptogressbar to keep pace with the each of the files uploaded?

```
    <button  id="loadfiles"class="btn"><span>Start Loading</span><span style="display: none">Stop Loading</span></button>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

var strFiles = 'SC2RFFBCRMEPOSAPP20131022.csv|SC2RFFBDEALERSORO20131022.csv|SC2ROFUOR00_ESHOP20131026.csv|SC2ROFUOR00_ESHOP20131027.csv|SC2ROFUOR00_ESHOP20131028.csv|SC2RFSFCRMEPOSAPP20131022.csv|SC2RFSFDEALERSORO20131022.csv|SC2ROSFWEBSHOPAPP20131022.csv|SC2RFRPCRMEPOSAPP20131022.csv|SC2RFRPDEALERSORO20131022.csv|SC2RORPOR00_ESHOP20131022.csv|SC2RORPWEBSHOPAPP20131022.csv|Active_range_20131022.csv|Active_range_20131023.csv|Active_range_20131024.csv|SC2ROZBOR00_SLRM_20131019(1).csv|SC2ROZBOR00_SLRM_20131019.csv' ;
var arrFiles = strFiles.split('|');
var strFileType = {Full:5,Scope:3,Proposal:4,ActiveRange:3,ForceValue:2} ;
var pragcycle = 0;
var step = 0 ;
var increment = 0;
var i=0


  $("#loadfiles").click(function(){

 for (key in strFileType)
  {  

    step = 100 / strFileType[key];
    pragcycle = pragcycle + strFileType[key];
    increment = 0;

  for (i;i<pragcycle;i++)
        {   

    var request =    $.ajax({
             url:'/quickadmin/php/admin/pages/AppLoadCSV.php',
             async: false,
             data: "basename=" + arrFiles[i] ,
             success:function() {

                    increment = increment + step;
                    $("." + key).attr("style","width: " + increment + "%");

                                }
                            })

        }


    }


  });


});




</script>
```

Comment: This is a hideously bad design. You're doing an http request for EVERY record you're uploading. 5000 records, 5000 http requests, 5000 chances for a network glitch to lose a record. That's a massive waste of bandwidth and processing time. You'd be better off using a normal file upload, with a normal upload progress meter on that. then processing that file in bulk on the server.

Comment: Hi Marc! The http request is for every file, and there will not be more than 30 files